# Accessing data in the RAM of one process from second process

Tags: android, security

I have security question (probably naive) related on how android uses RAM. Say I have long running service A that has reference to some data (object). Is it possible for another process to scrape the RAM information of service A and access the data associated with the service.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The standard Android way of doing this is to communicate via Binder interface. You should refer to the guide of Android bound service here: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

However, technically, binder interface won't let you to directly manipulate the memory of the other process. To do this, you might resort to linux shared memory. But this technology is also the basis of binder interface.

If you want to hack the memory of the other process, you might met the permission issue. You cannot access the memory of arbitrary process in /proc/pid/mem. But you can if you have root your android or you can exploit some vulnerability to get the root privilege.

I guess you have already known the technology to **[debug with the PTrace(1) Utility](http://www.secretmango.com/jimb/Whitepapers/ptrace/ptrace.html)**. About how to check/hack in memory, there is also a very good example which is used to root Android 2.2/2.3 devices called **[zergRush](https://github.com/revolutionary/zergRush)**.

Comment: So I think I may need to edit the intent of my question.  I was asking the question from the aspect of memory venerability to hack. Say the service A is storing sensitive data in RAM ( I know it can get killed and loose the information etc... and that is okay), can another process hack and get that information. What happens if my service runs in system space. Can a user space process still hack the data?

Answer (score 0):

There is an app called "Game Killer.apk" that has access to many other apps RAM data and can change this data while the apps are in execution. Is good for hacking some games on android. So if this app can get access to others apps RAM data, any other app can in a rooted android device.